# Editor capable of editing text using alternative representation

Tags: text-editor

I want to create editor for XML files using representation with less boilerplate. I'm looking for tools that will allow me to focus mostly on transformation from A to B and vice versa.

Concrete example for prototype solution:

storage format:

```
<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

editor format:

```
to: Tove
from: Jani
heading: Reminder
body: Don't forget me this weekend!
```

Answer (score 1):

The best XML editor I know of is [XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) by Altova. Amongs it's many features, XML Spy has a built in editor that lets you edit XML using a form. XML Spy is a bit pricey at 499 USD for the pro edition but it's worth every penny.

[image: XML Editor screenshot from Altova]

Answer (score 1):

If XML Spy is out of your price range, you can always try Eclipse. Eclipse provides support for XML in the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/). It does provide some form support but not as robust as XML Spy. The upside is that it's free (gratis). There may also be other XML tools available in the [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/site/XML).